# How to work with usdt using http api of tron node?

Tags: cryptocurrency, tron, cryptocurrency-token

I deployed a tron node for myself using this guide: [tron node](https://developers.tron.network/docs/deploy-the-fullnode-or-supernode).I was also able to connect to its http api. Question: How can I create and make transactions to usdt addresses using the http api? I understand how it's divided for a regular cryptocurrency, but usdt is a token, so it's a bit more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

**You can find the API endpoint in this page:**

https://developers.tron.network/reference/background

For example:
Shata Testnet endpoint will be: https://api.shasta.trongrid.io

**They also provide the way how to use API in many languages, Node, Ruby, PHP, Python, C, C#, C++, Java, Javascript, etc.:**

https://developers.tron.network/reference/get-account-info-by-address

For example:
Get account info by address
[https://api.shasta.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/{address}](https://api.shasta.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/%7Baddress%7D)

First, you should test your code by using their Official endpoint (Fullnode server), later you can replace the server endpoint to your fullnode (as long as your fullnode is installed correctly).

If you are able to run a Tron fullnode, I recommend you to connect to your node via RPC. It has greater power and more secure than using API connection.